# How to enable yasnippets for all modes?

Tags: company-mode, yasnippet

Company doesn't show snippets in some modes e.g. `python` or `sh`. Yet `yas/describe-tables` displays all snippets. In other modes e.g. `org`,`emacs-lisp`, snippets are shown as expected.

Looking at `company-diag` I don't see `company-yasnippets` loaded anywhere in `python-mode`.

```
Used backend: company-capf
```

While in the working org mode it returns

```
Used backend: (company-capf :with company-yasnippet)
```

Testing this variable (as proposed in [spacemac docu](http://spacemacs-default-company-backends%20%27(company-yasnippet))) didn't change anything:

```
spacemacs-default-company-backends '(company-yasnippet)
```

---

Environment:

yas-snippet-dirs:

`("/home/user/.emacs.d/private/snippets/" yasnippet-snippets-dir)`

`yas-global-mode t`

```
 (auto-completion :variables
                  auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t
                  auto-completion-enable-help-tooltip t)
 (python :variables
         python-backend 'lsp
         python-lsp-server 'pyright
         python-test-runner 'pytest
         python-enable-yapf-format-on-save t
         )
```

Where should I start looking?

---

Update:

Custom created snippets e.g. `/private/snippets/python-mode/foo.snippet` appear in a second list. In a different color and out-of-line position. It looks like multiple completion systems are interfering.

Gif: Python after enabling `auto-complete-mode` alongside `company-mode`

[image: screenshot]

Gif: Expected behavior (as in org mode and *company-mode* only):
[image: expected_gif]

Comment: Do you have any snippet files stored in the folders (within the `snippets` folder) labeled `python-mode` and/or `sh-mode`, or do you have a snippet inherit file `.yas-parents` in either of those folders so that snippets from other modes are inherited?  Have you enabled `yasnippet` globally as described in the `README.md` file?:  https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet

Comment: @lawlist No parents in neither directories. Does my question update help?

Comment: Do the snippets work correctly if you revert to the default spacemacs settings of `auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup` having a `nil` value?  Yasnippet comes with its own mechanism for triggering snippets when the user presses the tab key, and if more than one snippet matches the key at point, the available snippets to choose from are displayed.  See the section "**Multiples snippet with the same key**" https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/blob/master/doc/snippet-expansion.org  See also the function `yas-insert-snippet` ... "*Prompts you for possible snippet expansion ...*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Solved] Auto-completion support

**Disclaimer**: The configuration and setup mentioned in this guide are specific to `Spacemacs` only. The instructions provided may not be applicable or compatible with other Emacs setups or configurations.

I've successfully set up various completions in Spacemacs after trying several combinations. I'm sharing this solution here in case anyone else encounters the same dilemma.

### Yasnippet Auto-completion

The backend for yasnippet is `company-yasnippet`. You can integrate it into your Spacemacs configuration. There are two methods to get it working; choose only one. I used the second option in my `spacemacs` config file.

1. At your `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` add

```lisp
     (auto-completion :variables
                      auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t
                      auto-completion-enable-help-tooltip t
                      auto-completion-return-key-behavior 'complete
                      auto-completion-tab-key-behavior 'cycle ;;'complete 'cycle
                      auto-completion-enable-sort-by-usage t
                      auto-completion-idle-delay 0.0
                      :config
                      add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-yasnippet company-capf company-anaconda))
```

2. You can add to `dotspacemacs/user-config`  the following

```lisp
  ;; -------------------------------------------------------------
  ;;            Auto-completion - Back End Support
  ;; -------------------------------------------------------------
  (require 'company-yasnippet)
    (add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-yasnippet  company-capf company-anaconda))
```

### [Optional][bonus] Tabnine Auto-completion support

I like also to add `company-tabnine` to my back-ends completions. Here is how I did it.

1. Ensure you already installed the `tabnine` in `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` as:

```lisp
   dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(
                (company-tabnine) ;; for using tab-nine AI auto-assistance
)
```

2. Put in your `dotspacemacs/user-config` (similar to before)

```lisp
  ;; -------------------------------------------------------------
  ;;            Auto-completion - Back End Support
  ;; -------------------------------------------------------------
  (require 'company-yasnippet)
  (require 'company-tabnine)
  (add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-yasnippet company-tabnine  company-capf company-anaconda))
```

3. Install `tabnine` binary using `M-x: company-tabnine-install-binary` ( twice in `spacemacs` then write this command). It will be installed in your home directory (e.g. for my machine M1 macOS, it will be downloaded here `~/.TabNine/4.4.321/aarch64-apple-darwin`. Make sure it is executable by running the command below in this directory (read more [here](https://github.com/TommyX12/company-tabnine)).

```shell
chmod +x ~/.TabNine/4.4.321/aarch64-apple-darwin/*
```

It works now as you can see
[image: auto-completion support in action]

**NOTE**:

- [I think] changing the order of the company backends in the company-backends list will affect their order in the popup menu. Make sure to set auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t (read more [here](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+completion/auto-completion/README.html#snippets-directories))
- To investigate your back-end company support, you can use `<space-space>`  and type (M-x: `describe-variable`) then search for `company-backends` and you will see a `doc` popup showing all back-ends supported. For me they are

```lisp
Value:
((company-capf company-dabbrev-code . #1=(:with company-yasnippet))
 (company-semantic company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords . #1#)
 (company-files . #1#)
 (company-dabbrev . #1#))
Original value was 
(company-bbdb company-semantic company-cmake company-capf company-clang company-files
              (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords)
              company-oddmuse company-dabbrev)
Local in buffer .spacemacs; global value is 
((company-yasnippet company-tabnine company-lsp company-capf company-anaconda)
 company-bbdb company-semantic company-cmake company-capf company-clang company-files
 (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords)
 company-oddmuse company-dabbrev)
```

- `company-lsp` is no longer supported read the overview [here](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode)

Comment: In item 1 there is an extra parenthesis that should be removed on the line "auto-completion-idle-delay 0.0)"

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have removed it already.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, huge improvement for my daily workflow :) Note `company-lsp` is not supported by lsp-mode anymore. You might remove it from your answer.

Comment: I have updated the post, thank you for your feedback,

Answer (score 2):

Remove the extension `.snippet` from the name of any new snippet created . No snippets have such extension.

Assuming you have some python snippets, take into account the execution order - if your python mode is enabled after `yasnippets-snippets` package, then at the end of your python configuration add the expression `(yas-reload-all)` to reload all snippets.